# insert array into mysql for mulitple rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 3 tables
and executed an array

```
$result = mysql_query("Select * from table_3");
while($r[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($r);
echo "<PRE>";
```

The output is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [batch_id] => 1
        [seq_id] => 1
        [q_id] => 2046
        [a1] => 0
        [a2] => 1
        [a3] => 2
        [a4] => 3
        [a5] => 4

    )

[1] => Array
    (
         [batch_id] => 1
        [seq_id] => 2
        [q_id] => 2046
        [a1] => 0
        [a2] => 2
        [a3] => 1
        [a4] => 3
        [a5] => 4        
        )
[2] => Array
    (
         [batch_id] => 1
        [seq_id] => 3
        [q_id] => 2046
        [a1] => 2
        [a2] => 0
        [a3] => 2
        [a4] => 2
        [a5] => 1
    )
```

)

I need to insert the array into two tables of mysql.The row which have brackets are the examples of what I need to insert

Structure for table_1 :

table_1.id should be the batch_id+seq_id of the array (e.g. 11 for the array[0]).

table_1.s_id get hard coded

```
id   |   s_id    | submit_time
-----------------------------------
2205 |    80     | 1360051287
2214 |    80     | 1360811596
(11) |   (80)    | (1351024912) 
(12) |   (80)    | (1359741512) 
(13) |   (80)    | (1356573212)
```

Structure for table_2:

table_2.id is auto increment

```
  id   |   r_id   | q_id   | c_id  | ranking 
-------------------------------------------
  18965|  2205    | 2046   |   a1  |   0
  18966|  2205    | 2046   |   a2  |   2
  18967|  2205    | 2046   |   a3  |   3
  18968|  2205    | 2046   |   a4  |   1    
  18969|  2205    | 2046   |   a5  |   4
  19965|  2214    | 2046   |   a1  |   0
  19966|  2214    | 2046   |   a2  |   1
  19967|  2214    | 2046   |   a3  |   1
  19968|  2214    | 2046   |   a4  |   2    
  19969|  2214    | 2046   |   a5  |   3
(20965)|  (11)    | (2046) | (a1)  |   (0)
(20966)|  (11)    | (2046) | (a2)  |   (1)
(20967)|  (11)    | (2046) | (a3)  |   (2)
(20968)|  (11)    | (2046) | (a4)  |   (3)   
(20969)|  (11)    | (2046) | (a5)  |   (4)
(21965)|  (12)    | (2046) | (a1)  |   (0)
(21966)|  (12)    | (2046) | (a2)  |   (2)
(21967)|  (12)    | (2046) | (a3)  |   (1)
(21968)|  (12)    | (2046) | (a4)  |   (3)   
(21969)|  (12)    | (2046) | (a5)  |   (4)
(22965)|  (13)    | (2046) | (a1)  |   (2)
(22966)|  (13)    | (2046) | (a2)  |   (0)
(22967)|  (13)    | (2046) | (a3)  |   (2)
(22968)|  (13)    | (2046) | (a4)  |   (2)   
(22969)|  (13)    | (2046) | (a5)  |   (1)
```

Can someone teach me how to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand how you generate values for table2. But for table_1 why are you taking data into PHP? You should use following sql command for this:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(id) SELECT CONCAT(batch_id, seq_id) FROM table_3
```